# Extend Log4JLogger and invoke subclass during runtime

Tags: java, inheritance, log4j

I currently am using the `SocketAppender` in Log4J and have run into some issues with passing data over to a remote host, specifically around losing `LocationInfo` (class name, line number, etc).  What I have done is the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;

public class MyLogger extends Log4JLogger  
{  
    ...
       public void debug(Object message)  
       {   
           String extra = "Extra!";  
           super.debug(message + extra);
       }   
    ...
}
```

At runtime how can I change the following code to grab `MyLogger` instead of `Log4JLogger`?

```
private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Test.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to extends Logger but implement your own Appender or extend the base Log4J Appender you need.
For example you can extend [AppenderSkeleton](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html).

I cannot imagine exactly why do you need it. Another possibility could be use Log4J [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).

Comment: MDC and NDC do not work very well when you have a distributed environment (according to my reading).  The primary issue is that SocketAppender eats the LocationInfo

Comment: So you lose LocationInfo even if the doc (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) say that "...the event will be logged with the same time stamp, NDC, location info as if it were logged locally by the client..."? It is a bug?

Comment: it is either a bug or a problem with my configuration file.  See my other question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944681/log4j-socketappender-swallows-debug-information-from-remote-clients

Comment: I've read both your questions, interesting issue, it would appear that it could be a bug in log4j. You can debug it and find out of course, just grab the log4j source. To answer this question, I would agree with dash1e and create a subclass of SocketAppender - that could tack on the appropriate location info into the message. GL HTH.

Comment: Missing LocationInfo="true" on "async" appender. I put answer on the other topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944681/log4j-socketappender-swallows-debug-information-from-remote-clients)